# Что такое "пирожки"?

Tags: поэзия

В последнее время в моду вошли стихи "пирожки". Я часто встречаю их в интернете, но, кроме отсутствия рифмы и знаков препинания, никаких закономерностей не вижу.
Объясните мне, пожалуйста, что такое стихи "пирожки", в чем их принцип, есть ли какой-то определенный размер для них, на какие темы их чаще всего пишут и какие должны быть соблюдены требования? И обязательно ли для них полное отсутствие пунктуации?
А еще, почему, собственно, они называются "пирожки"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Про историю "пирожков" можно почитать [здесь](http://www.stihi.ru/2012/01/26/560). Сейчас пирожки выкладывают в специально созданной [группе](http://vk.com/perawki) вконтакте. На мой взгляд, очень интересная идея.